# Convert float64 column to int64 in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I tried to convert a column from data type `float64` to `int64` using:

```
df['column name'].astype(int64)
```

but got an error:

> NameError: name 'int64' is not defined

The column has number of people but was formatted as `7500000.0`, any idea how I can simply change this `float64` into `int64`?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Solution for pandas **0.24+** for converting numeric with missing values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column name':[7500000.0,7500000.0, np.nan]})
print (df['column name'])
0    7500000.0
1    7500000.0
2          NaN
Name: column name, dtype: float64

df['column name'] = df['column name'].astype(np.int64)
```

> ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

```
#http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html
df['column name'] = df['column name'].astype('Int64')
print (df['column name'])
0    7500000
1    7500000
2        NaN
Name: column name, dtype: Int64
```

---

I think you need cast to [`numpy.int64`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.types.html):

```
df['column name'].astype(np.int64)
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column name':[7500000.0,7500000.0]})
print (df['column name'])
0    7500000.0
1    7500000.0
Name: column name, dtype: float64

df['column name'] = df['column name'].astype(np.int64)
#same as
#df['column name'] = df['column name'].astype(pd.np.int64)
print (df['column name'])
0    7500000
1    7500000
Name: column name, dtype: int64
```

If some `NaN`s in columns need replace them to some `int` (e.g. `0`) by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html), because `type` of `NaN` is `float`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column name':[7500000.0,np.nan]})

df['column name'] = df['column name'].fillna(0).astype(np.int64)
print (df['column name'])
0    7500000
1          0
Name: column name, dtype: int64
```

Also check [documentation - missing data casting rules](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#missing-data-casting-rules-and-indexing)

EDIT:

Convert values with `NaN`s is buggy:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column name':[7500000.0,np.nan]})

df['column name'] = df['column name'].values.astype(np.int64)
print (df['column name'])
0                7500000
1   -9223372036854775808
Name: column name, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Got error: ValueError: Cannot convert NA to integer for the first code .astype(np.int64).

Comment: If need convert `NaN` to `0`, use `fillna(0)` - see my second paragraph code - `df['column name'] = df['column name'].fillna(0).astype(np.int64)`.

Comment: does not work. Python 3.5 --> df_test["column"] = gdf_test['column'].apply(lambda x: np.int64(x)) worked

Comment: how to check if a particular column having 0 as a decimal point. The problem occurred due to empty value and column got converted to float64 so now I have to convert it int64. And columns are not fixed so have to make generic something in case. What can I do?

Comment: Once `NaN` is filled with other integer values, `np.int64` is no longer required, `int64` works just fine. But could anyone help to explain the difference between these two types of int64 in short?

Answer (score 11):

You can need to pass in the string `'int64'`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1.0, 2.0]})  # some test dataframe

>>> df['a'].astype('int64')
0    1
1    2
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

There are some alternative ways to specify 64-bit integers:

```
>>> df['a'].astype('i8')      # integer with 8 bytes (64 bit)
0    1
1    2
Name: a, dtype: int64

>>> import numpy as np
>>> df['a'].astype(np.int64)  # native numpy 64 bit integer
0    1
1    2
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Or use `np.int64` directly on your column (but it returns a [`numpy.array`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html)):

```
>>> np.int64(df['a'])
array([1, 2], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: ValueError: Cannot convert NA to integer

Comment: @MCGCode That's not so good, because `NaN`s can't be converted to integers (at least not with a meaningful value because only floats support NaN and Inf). What value should these have in the result?

Comment: I guess 0. So if it is NaN, it's not populated so I keep it at zero.

Comment: Then you can use `df['column name'].fillna(0)` instead of `df['column name']` and use any approach I mentioned above.

Answer (score 7):

This seems to be a little buggy in Pandas 0.23.4?

If there are np.nan values then this will throw an error as expected:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].astype(np.int64)
```

But doesn't change any values from float to int as I would expect if "ignore" is used:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].astype(np.int64,errors='ignore')
```

It worked if I first converted np.nan:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].fillna(0).astype(np.int64)
df['col'] = df['col'].astype(np.int64)
```

Now I can't figure out how to get null values back in place of the zeroes since this will convert everything back to float again:

```
df['col']  = df['col'].replace(0,np.nan)
```

Answer (score 4):

consider using

`df['column name'].astype('Int64')`

`nan` will be changed to `NaN`

Comment: to replace the column
`df['column name'] = df['column name'].astype('Int64')`

Answer (score 1):

if you have to convert float64 to int64 you have to use numpy like the exemple below:

```
import numpy as np
df['column name'].astype(np.int)
```