# Change column type to int64 pandas geopandas best practice

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.5, geopandas

I am trying to convert a column containing floats with only .0 as decimals to an integer64. I found some older [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43956335/convert-float64-column-to-int64-in-pandas) on this forum but they didn't seem to work anymore. Eventually I used:

```
df_test["column_name"] = df_test['column_name'].apply(lambda x: np.int64(x))
```

I was wondering if this is best practice in pandas and how this compares [to to_numeric()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-data-type-of-columns-in-pandas)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `pandas`, this would work:

```
df_test['column_name'] = df_test['column_name'].astype('int64')
```

as `geopandas` is built on top of `pandas`, this should work as well. As for how it compares to `to_numeric`, they are both vectorized, and comparable as far as speed goes:

Testing the speed of `astype` method vs the `to_numeric` method for a modest sized Series, I got an average of `0.00007522797584533691` seconds for `astype` and `0.0003248021602630615` seconds for `to_numeric`.

Comment: Great! I parsed np.int64 instead of the string "int64"

Comment: Wish i could accept both answers but the speed comparison is helpful

Answer (score 2):

Your best option, if the most optimal integer format is required:

```
df_test["column_name"] = pd.to_numeric(df_test['column_name'], downcast='integer')
```

This is vectorised, `df.series.apply` is a loop and is slow.

If you really need `np.int64`, see [@sacul's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48812925/9209546).