# Pandas, astype(int) applied to float column returns negative numbers

Tags: pandas, type-conversion

My task is to read data from excel to dataframe. The data is a bit messy and to clean that up I've done:

```
df_1 = pd.read_excel(offers[0])
df_1 = df_1.rename(columns={'Наименование [Дата Файла: 29.05.2019 время: 10:29:42 ]':'good_name', 
                     'Штрихкод':'barcode', 
                     'Цена шт. руб.':'price',
                     'Остаток': 'balance'
                    })
df_1 = df_1[new_columns]
# I don't know why but without replacing NaN with another char code doesn't work
df_1.barcode = df_1.barcode.fillna('_')
# remove all non-numeric characters
df_1.barcode = df_1.barcode.apply(lambda row: re.sub('[^0-9]', '', row))
# convert str to numeric
df_1.barcode = pd.to_numeric(df_1.barcode, downcast='integer').fillna(0)
df_1.head()
```

It returns column barcode with type float64 (why so?)

```
0    0.000000e+00
1    7.613037e+12
2    7.613037e+12
3    7.613034e+12
4    7.613035e+12
Name: barcode, dtype: float64
```

Then I try to convert that column to integer.

```
df_1.barcode = df_1.barcode.astype(int)
```

But I keep getting silly negative numbers.

```
df_1.barcode[0:5]
0             0
1   -2147483648
2   -2147483648
3   -2147483648
4   -2147483648

Name: barcode, dtype: int32
```

**Thanks to @Will and @micric eventually I've got a solution.**

```
df_1 = pd.read_excel(offers[0])
df_1 = df_1[new_columns]
# replacing NaN with 0, it'll help to convert the column explicitly to dtype integer
df_1.barcode = df_1.barcode.fillna('0')
# remove all non-numeric characters
df_1.barcode = df_1.barcode.apply(lambda row: re.sub('[^0-9]', '', row))
# convert str to integer
df_1.barcode = pd.to_numeric(df_1.barcode, downcast='integer')
```

**Resume:**

- pd.to_numeric converts NaN to float64. As a result from column with
  both NaN and not-Nan values we should expect column dtype float64.
- Check size of number you're dealing with. int32 has its limit, which
  is 2**32 = 4294967296.
  Thanks a lot for your help, guys!

Comment: Could you tell me the output of `print(pd.__version__)`?

Comment: pandas version is 0.20.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many questions in one.

So your expected dtype...

```
pd.to_numeric(df_1.barcode, downcast='integer').fillna(0)
```

`pd.to_numeric` downcast to integer would give you an integer, however, you have NaNs in your data and pandas needs to use a float64 type to represent NaNs

Comment: You're right, many thanks for your help. After editing code so it fills NaN first <df_1.barcode = df_1.barcode.fillna(1)>, then converts column to numeric, code works as it supposed, meaning eventually I've got output <barcode      9820 non-null int64>

Answer (score 14):

That number is a 32 bit lower limit. Your number is out of the int32 range you are trying to use, so it returns you the limit (notice that 2**32 = 4294967296, divided by 2 2147483648 that is your number).

You should use astype(int64) instead.

Comment: It actually should be `astype(np.int64)`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43956335/convert-float64-column-to-int64-in-pandas

Answer (score 7):

I ran into the same problem as OP, using

`astype(np.int64)`

solved mine, see the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43956335/convert-float64-column-to-int64-in-pandas).

I like this solution because it's consistent with my habit of changing the column type of `pandas` column, maybe someone could check the performance of these solutions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solved my problem. I was utterly confounded by this behavior as I was trying to convert an abnormally long ID field to integer.

Comment: Please be warned that this solution did not work for me while the accepted answer did. I have no idea why astype(np.int64) changed 1 to 0 seemingly at random.